# jQuery - Twitter Bootstrap - close all popovers on body's any elements focus

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus, popover

I'm trying closing any `popover` is opened when `any body element` (not the popover itself) `is focused`,

so i do:

```
 $(document.body).on('focus focusout focusin', function(e) {
  if( e.target.classList.contains('popover') ){return false;}
  else{
    $('*').popover('hide');
  }
  // code to close the popover
});
```

this works great on `Chrome` but not on `FF`, on `FF` i need to `focusin and focusout` before the popover is closed.

here is my example working only for chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/CU5U5/4/

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An alternative:

```
$(document).on('focus', ':not(.popover)', function(){
    $('.popover').popover('hide');
});
```

Edit:

So as it turns out, my above answer is incorrect.  You need to call .popover('hide') on the element the popover was instantiated on... not the .popover itself.  AND you need to stop propagation of the click event on the link (i.e., return false in click handler) so it doesn't bubble up to the document root.  See this for an answer, http://jsfiddle.net/aFacG/1/.

HTML

```
<a data-content="a popover" id="mypopover" href="#">click me</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mypopover").popover();

  $(document).on('click', function(){
      $("#mypopover").popover('hide');
  });

  $('#mypopover').click(function(){
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: This should work perfectly @Badaboooooom it is better than my answer! `+1`

Comment: provide a example of your code failing. This code *should* work and if it is not that means your question does not contain enough information. http://jsfiddle.net if possible use this (or similar tool)

Comment: with this i can't get the popover to hide, i focused on any element on the body , it doesn't hides neither on FF and CH :(

Comment: It's possible instead of "focus" you should try just using a "click" event... ?  This would mean if someone clicks anywhere else on the page EXCEPT a popover, it will close all popovers.

Comment: @Badaboooooom please heed rlemon's words... we need a demo of this **not** working...

Comment: @joeltine tryed with no results

Comment: Ok, I've actually figured it out... when you do .popover('hide') it has to be on the element you instantiated the popover on, not the actual .popover element that gets generated.  Also, you have to prevent event bubbling on the anchor tag itself (stopPropagation). See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aFacG/1/

Comment: I've followed the above example and it works fine for me but there is one issue that when I click on the element for the first time, the popover doesn't appear and if click the same element second time, the popover appears. anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 9):

Being very simplistic:

```
$('.popover').remove();
```

Comment: This seems like such an elegant solution (that worked for me) - could anyone please elaborate as to what this solution does (as I'm concerned it may prevent future popovers working in the page). Thank you

Answer (score 8):

The problem with the current accepted answer is that popover hides even when you click inside the tooltip (bad if you have an element you want to interact with inside the popover..like an input field).

Use the [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on your popover container to prevent the hide event from bubbling up the DOM.

UPDATE(bootstrap url changed):[http://jsfiddle.net/bNvX7/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/digitalmaster/bNvX7/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Initialize popover on element
    $("#mypopover").popover();

    //Attach click handler to document
    $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
        $("#mypopover").popover('hide');
    });

    //Dont hide when I click anything inside #container
    $('#container').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: I just had to solve this problem myself.. so figured it would be great to add to this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Calling

```
$('.popover').popover('hide');
```

will close all currently opened popovers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more generic approach that requires just one handler and works for all popovers where the toggle/link contains attribute data-rel="popover", e.g.:

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-rel="popover">toggle</a>
```

JS

```
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    var $clicked = $(event.target);

    if ($clicked.closest('[data-rel="popover"]').length) {
      return;
    } else if ($clicked.closest('.popover').length) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      $('[data-rel="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
        // Part 1: initialize the popver
        var button = template.find(".itemInfo button");
        // add a class name to identify the target later.
        button.addClass("popover-toggle");

        var content = $("<div>test</div>");

        button.popover({
            container:"body",
            content: content,
            html:true,
            placement:"top",
            title:"Popover title",
            trigger:'click'
        });

        // Part 2: add click event listener 
        $(document).on("click", function(event){
            var target = $(event.target);
            $.each( $(".popover-toggle"), function(index, value){
                var _target = $(value);
                // not click on the button and not click on the popover it self
                if( !target.is( _target ) && target.closest(".popover").length == 0 ){
                    _target.popover("hide");
                }
            });
        });
```

Not the best practice but it works fine on both Chrome and FF.